Unitary matrix factorization with diagonal matrix implies eigenvalues
Let $A=U\Sigma V^*$ be the singular value decomposition of the matrix $A\in\mathbb{C}^{n\times m}$ and $\sigma_1,...,\sigma_r$ are its first non zero singular values. I wish to show the following:
$\text{The eigenvalues of $AA^*$ are $\sigma_1^2$, $\sigma_2^2$,...,$\sigma_r^2$}$.
So what I did was calculating $AA^*$, which yielded :
$$AA^*=U\Sigma\Sigma^*U^*$$
Here I wondered, since $AA^*$ is hermitian, can I deduce that $\Sigma \Sigma^*$ contains all my eigenvalues because of the spectral theorem (the matrix is diagonal and $U$ is unitary) ? I believe this is wrong but I would like any input on this anyway.

You can just check it directly. Let $u_i$ by the $i$th column of $U$ and $\sigma_i$ be the $i$th diagonal entry of $\Sigma$. We then have
$$
AA^*u_i = (U\Sigma\Sigma^*U^*)u_i = U\Sigma^2e_i = U(\sigma_i^2e_i) = \sigma_i^2u_i.
$$
If the matrix was not symmetric and the left and right unitary matrices were not conjugates of each other, then you would end up with $A v_i = \sigma u_i$, which is not generally an eigenvector.
